# android fragment with activity calleded twice

Tags: android

My activity contain one Fragment. Issue is my activity calling twice. i couldn't find the solution Calling this activity also only one place. I don't know exact reason

My code :

```
 Activity

    public class CoursesActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.courses_main);
        System.out.println("====Courses************************************************************8");
    }
}
```

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/gray_thread" 
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.abc.mob.courses.CousesFragment" ></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.abc.mob.whathappenfeed.DiscussionFeedFragment" ></fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please guide me.... I faced this issue more than 2 days. please

Comment: Is this your main `Activity`? if not provide the calling code please.

Comment: Yes.Courses Activity is main activity

Answer (score 1):

Well Your `Activity` is loading a `layout` (`courses_main.xml`) that already contains two fragments!

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        ...
```

and

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        ...
```

Comment: please suggest any idea?

Comment: if you want load only one fragment you must delete the fragment that isn´t necessary, and remove references to that fragment in your activity :)